# eclipse, your project has error ,please fix it

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an android application integrated with google maps v2, i am using support v4, now i want to integrate with facebook, i downloaded the facebook sdk, and i used it in another program and everything is perfect, now i want to use the facebook sdk in my main project, i imported it as i did in the dummy project put i has a problem because facebook sdk also has suppor v4 jar, i deleted my support v4 and there is no syntax error nor compilar error nor any error.

#### But the eclipse put an `x` sign in the project and when i wanted to run it , it told me that my project has errors, where is that error please, help me to find it or to any thing , thanks

Comment: Please check your project properties...

Comment: @AlexVogel there is no error there,

Comment: @AlexVogel would u tell me please how to figure the error, is there a tool in eclipse or something ?

Comment: eureka eureka eureka eureka eureka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had faced most issues you faced. I had it resolved. Eclipse for some reason chose to keep facebook project is Java 1.5 eventhough my eclipse preferences had the setting to use Java compiler 1.6.

So, go to Project Properties in facebook project and select the java compiler to be 1.6. This solved my problem. Hope it solves yours too.